# Nash equilibrium: comparing different definitions

Tags: game-theory

A Nash equilibrium seems to be defined in different ways in different books. Sometimes a Nash equilibrium refers to a single strategy (Definition $1$ below) and sometimes a Nash equilibrium is defined for a pair of strategies (Definition $2$ below).

**Definition $1$**: A strategy $\mathbf{p}$ is a Nash equilibrium if it is a best reply to itself (e.g., Hofbauer and Sigmund *Evolutionary Games and Population Dynamics*, p. 62.)

**Definition $2$**: The pair $(\mathbf{p}, \mathbf{q})$ is a Nash equilibrium if $\mathbf{p}$ is a best response to $\mathbf{q}$ and $\mathbf{q}$ is a best response to $\mathbf{p}$ (e.g., Broom and Rychtar *Game theoretical models in biology*).

*My question is this.* How are these definitions related? What is the definition of Nash equilibrium that is used by the Nash existence theorem$?$

---

**Further comments**:

1. I initially thought that the Definition 1 is a particular case of the Definition 2 for symmetric games, but I don't think this is true. For instance, consider a symmetric $2\times 2$ game with payoff matrix:

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
    & A & B\\
    A& a & b\\
    B& c & d
  \end{array}
$$

where $a<c$ and $b>d$. According to Definition 1, neither $A$ nor $B$ is a Nash equilibrium (because neither $A$ nor $B$ are a best reply to itself). But according to Definition 2, the pairs $(A,B)$ and $(B,A)$ are Nash equilibria.

2. Sometimes, Nash equilibrium is still defined in another way (as A. Sh. pointed out, this is a generalization of Definition 2 for n players):

**Definition $3$**: A Nash equilibrium is a strategy profile in which every player is playing a best response to the current strategy profile.

The above definition appears in Gintis *Game Theory Evolving*, p. 43. It is also the definition that appears in the Wikipedia article on Nash equilibrium: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash_equilibrium#Formal_definition

Comment: How would a single strategy (as per definition 1) also be an equilibrium? I have only encountered the second definition (and its extensions to several players) so far. Maybe definition 1 applies in one-person games?

Comment: @A.Sh The cases that I've seen the Definition 1 being applied are for symmetric two-player games.

Comment: Ok, then I believe it is safe to assume that definition 1 is a simplification for that particular scenario, although I cannot see why it holds water at the moment. However, definition 2 is the standard, and is the one used in the existence theorem, and that should answer your question.

Comment: @A.Sh I thought that the Definition 1 could be derived from Definition 2 once we assume that we are dealing with symmetric games. But I think they give different answers for symmetric games. I added an example to my question to explain why I think so.

Comment: Be more precise about the context of the first definition. Is it really given as a Definition in the textbook (I do not have it unfortunately) or as a *sufficient* condition (but *not necessary*) for a strategy to be used in a Nash equilibrium of a symmetric game? Clearly the second definition is the correct one, but the first one has to be also correct in the context used by the author (because textbook - authors never make mistakes :))

Comment: @Stef This is a great point. Hofbauer and Sigmund say that a Nash equilibrium "is a strategy which is a best reply to itself." So I believe that this being the best reply to itself is at least a sufficient condition for being a Nash equilibrium. I added the page number in case someone wants to check it out.

Comment: I checked it out, but didn't get too much wiser. I did however realize that if they mean that $(p,p)$ is a Nash equilibrium, then $p$ is of course a best reply to itself. For an arbitrary NE though, falsum's example sure breaks that definition. I think the authors might be a bit sloppy in their notation in using definition 1? (Why else call a strategy an equilibrium, that doesn't type-check at all…)

Comment: Regarding that third definition, it reduces to definition 2 in the case of 2 players, it's just a definition that admits arbitrary numbers of players.

Comment: @A.Sh Hmmm It seems to be that the Definition 2 is considering the payoff for both players, whereas the Definition 3 is only considering the payoff of a single player. Am I missing something?

Comment: Never mind. The definition is for every player $i$. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Definition 3** is the correct definition of Nash equilibrium ***of a general $n$-player game***.

**Definition 2** is a special case of **Def 3** in ***a general $2$-player game***.

**Definition 1** is the definition of a **Symmetric Nash equilibrium** in ***a $2$-player game***. And note that Symmetric Nash equilibrium is a proper subset of Nash equilibrium, and so strictly speaking, **Def 1** should not be taken as a definition of **Nash equilibrium**.

Answer (score 1):

The first definition refers to a special case of a symmetric game. The second one is more general and is a standard one, as far as I know.